# Webpack - misunderstanding and large bundles

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm having a hard time setting up a proper Webpack config. My development bundle.js comes out to 14.6mb, while my production is 23mb. The size of my source is only 455kb (js, css, images)... So this seems to be way off, let alone the production being bigger than the dev bundle. Also some images seem to get distorted/stretched out. I can not truly understand  what is going on (yes I've spent much time on google for this) or how to properly setup my Webpack config for proper optimization.

**Edit 1**
This seems to be an issue with Uglify. When I take it out, the build is at 6MB.

**Edit 2**
Optimized the build and got it down to 2mb, still working for a more efficient solution

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var merge = require('merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var webpackConfig = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

  webpackConfig = merge(webpackConfig,{
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry : [
      './src/client/index.js'
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'},
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap') }
    ]},
    plugins : [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        }
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("app.css"),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})
    ]  
  });

}else{

  webpackConfig = merge(webpackConfig,{
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname,
        query: {
          optional: ['runtime'],
          stage: 2,
          env: {
            development: {
              plugins: [
                'react-transform'
              ],
              extra: {
                'react-transform': {
                  transforms: [{
                    transform:  'react-transform-hmr',
                    imports: ['react'],
                    locals:  ['module']
                  },
                  {
                    transform: 'react-transform-catch-errors',
                    imports: ['react','redbox-react' ]
                  }
                ]}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'},
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
    ]},
    entry : [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      './src/client/index.js'
    ],
    plugins : [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]  
  });

}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Webpack-Bundle-Size-Analyzer:

```
plotly.js: 2.59 MB (46.6%)
  <self>: 2.59 MB (100%)
react: 590.99 KB (10.4%)
  <self>: 590.99 KB (100%)
lodash: 481.66 KB (8.46%)
  <self>: 481.66 KB (100%)
react-bootstrap: 275.43 KB (4.84%)
  <self>: 275.43 KB (100%)
leaflet: 217.5 KB (3.82%)
  <self>: 217.5 KB (100%)
core-js: 154.18 KB (2.71%)
  <self>: 154.18 KB (100%)
immutable: 139.19 KB (2.44%)
  <self>: 139.19 KB (100%)
react-leaflet: 100.1 KB (1.76%)
  <self>: 100.1 KB (100%)
react-router: 72.15 KB (1.27%)
  <self>: 72.15 KB (100%)
lodash-compat: 67.98 KB (1.19%)
  <self>: 67.98 KB (100%)
react-overlays: 63.65 KB (1.12%)
  react-prop-types: 2.94 KB (4.61%)
    <self>: 2.94 KB (100%)
  <self>: 60.72 KB (95.4%)
history: 46.16 KB (0.810%)
  <self>: 46.16 KB (100%)
buffer: 41.91 KB (0.736%)
  isarray: 132 B (0.308%)
    <self>: 132 B (100%)
  <self>: 41.78 KB (99.7%)
fbjs: 34.35 KB (0.603%)
  <self>: 34.35 KB (100%)
validator: 30.66 KB (0.538%)
  <self>: 30.66 KB (100%)
redux-router: 21.57 KB (0.379%)
  <self>: 21.57 KB (100%)
regenerator: 20.92 KB (0.367%)
  <self>: 20.92 KB (100%)
redux: 18.43 KB (0.324%)
  <self>: 18.43 KB (100%)
react-redux: 18.08 KB (0.317%)
  <self>: 18.08 KB (100%)
react-proxy: 16.81 KB (0.295%)
  <self>: 16.81 KB (100%)
dom-helpers: 15.56 KB (0.273%)
  <self>: 15.56 KB (100%)
redbox-react: 15.55 KB (0.273%)
  object-assign: 896 B (5.63%)
    <self>: 896 B (100%)
  <self>: 14.68 KB (94.4%)
whatwg-fetch: 9.69 KB (0.170%)
  <self>: 9.69 KB (100%)
uncontrollable: 8.71 KB (0.153%)
  <self>: 8.71 KB (100%)
error-stack-parser: 7.99 KB (0.140%)
  <self>: 7.99 KB (100%)
webpack-hot-middleware: 7.33 KB (0.129%)
  strip-ansi: 161 B (2.15%)
    <self>: 161 B (100%)
  ansi-regex: 145 B (1.93%)
    <self>: 145 B (100%)
  <self>: 7.03 KB (95.9%)
redux-undo: 7.29 KB (0.128%)
  <self>: 7.29 KB (100%)
redux-logger: 6.48 KB (0.114%)
  <self>: 6.48 KB (100%)
babel-runtime: 5.38 KB (0.0945%)
  <self>: 5.38 KB (100%)
style-loader: 5.38 KB (0.0944%)
  <self>: 5.38 KB (100%)
react-prop-types: 5.18 KB (0.0910%)
  <self>: 5.18 KB (100%)
deep-equal: 3.8 KB (0.0668%)
  <self>: 3.8 KB (100%)
react-transform-hmr: 3.6 KB (0.0633%)
  <self>: 3.6 KB (100%)
base64-js: 3.49 KB (0.0613%)
  <self>: 3.49 KB (100%)
stackframe: 3.4 KB (0.0597%)
  <self>: 3.4 KB (100%)
keycode: 2.67 KB (0.0470%)
  <self>: 2.67 KB (100%)
react-transform-catch-errors: 2.66 KB (0.0467%)
  <self>: 2.66 KB (100%)
process: 2.01 KB (0.0353%)
  <self>: 2.01 KB (100%)
ieee754: 2.01 KB (0.0352%)
  <self>: 2.01 KB (100%)
warning: 1.76 KB (0.0310%)
  <self>: 1.76 KB (100%)
invariant: 1.48 KB (0.0260%)
  <self>: 1.48 KB (100%)
query-string: 1.44 KB (0.0253%)
  <self>: 1.44 KB (100%)
react-deep-force-update: 1.26 KB (0.0222%)
  <self>: 1.26 KB (100%)
classnames: 1.08 KB (0.0189%)
  <self>: 1.08 KB (100%)
css-loader: 640 B (0.0110%)
  <self>: 640 B (100%)
redux-thunk: 375 B (0.00643%)
  <self>: 375 B (100%)
webpack: 251 B (0.00430%)
  <self>: 251 B (100%)
babel-core: 247 B (0.00424%)
  <self>: 247 B (100%)
global: 243 B (0.00417%)
  <self>: 243 B (100%)
isomorphic-fetch: 233 B (0.00400%)
  <self>: 233 B (100%)
strict-uri-encode: 182 B (0.00312%)
  <self>: 182 B (100%)
react-dom: 63 B (0.00108%)
  <self>: 63 B (100%)
<self>: 502.91 KB (8.83%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know too much about images in your package. But javascript (or any other text) files can be minified and gzipped. Minification should be done via webpack, and gzip is the feature of your web server.

I also do not recommend to include any images to your javascript `bundle.js`, it's not a good practice.

So basically solution is:

1. Minify js files
2. Enable gzip feature for js files
3. Remove images from your js/css

Comment: aren't I already doing minification here: `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})`

Comment: @Michael-R does it work? Can you see at your final package if it's minified?

Comment: @Michael-R what about images? Do you really want to include them in your `css`?

Comment: I don't particularly need to, but the image folder is only 132kb, really just medium-to-small sized icons

Comment: @Michael-R but why it's 23 mb? You mentioned that plotly.js is about 3MB, and it's about 50%. So it should be total of 6MB. Where are the rest 17MB?

Comment: it seems that there is something flawed in either my UglifyJS config, or the plugin itself, as taking it out creates a build back at 6mb

Comment: I'm happy you was able to narrow it down! Probably it includes source maps or something. Go ahead with your new approach and share your solution with us!

Comment: I gave you the up, but I'm still working for a more efficient solution, won't post an answer until I solve that. Appreciate your input though.